# Calling wizard window from existing opened window in odoo 10?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am setting up multiple wizards inside main form view. When i click on action type button(Open Wizard), this will open 1st wizard window. This wizard opened wizard also have a button to open 2nd new wizard (Open New Wizard). After performing action on this 2nd wizard. The current Opened wizard(New Wizard) will close and redirect to MAIN form view instead previous wizard. How can we solve this issue?